# Why is trying to create an expo app resulting in an error?

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, npx

I created a github repo and cloned it to my local machine and attempted to create an expo project in it. It keeps giving me the same error:

```
PS C:\Users\2025a\Documents\Code> npm create expo-app --template
√ What is your app named? ... welly-studies
× Something went wrong in downloading and extracting the project files: ENOENT: no such file or directory, copyfile 'C:\Users\2025a\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c9e3ae45b91c6e00\node_modules\create-expo-app\template\gitignore' -> 'C:\Users\2025a\Documents\Code\welly-studies\.gitignore'
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, copyfile 'C:\Users\2025a\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c9e3ae45b91c6e00\node_modules\create-expo-app\template\gitignore' -> 'C:\Users\2025a\Documents\Code\welly-studies\.gitignore'
node:internal/errors:497
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "code" argument must be of type number. Received type string ('ENOENT')
    at process.set [as exitCode] (node:internal/bootstrap/node:123:9)
    at process.exit (node:internal/process/per_thread:188:24)
    at C:\Users\2025a\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c9e3ae45b91c6e00\node_modules\create-expo-app\build\index.js:77:736
    at <anonymous>
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async run (C:\Users\2025a\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c9e3ae45b91c6e00\node_modules\create-expo-app\build\index.js:77:704) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}

Node.js v20.9.0
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\2025a\Documents\Code
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c create-expo-app

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\2025a\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-30T20_28_51_453Z-debug-0.lo
```